# check if function one to one or onto

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

for example  f(x) = x^2
I know if we get same result from different value will be not one to one in other words if the power odd will be one to one

- $(-2)^2=4$
- $2^2=4$

But how do I check it is onto or not. The co domain not given in the exam

Answer (score 0):

It can be assumed in the context of the level of mathematics you seem to be at that if the codomain is not mentioned, then it is going to be the whole of $\mathbb R$

So, in order to prove a function is onto, you need to show that for all elements of $\mathbb R$, there exists an element of the domain (also $\mathbb R$ in this context) which maps to that element.

Knowing as you do that the square of a number is always non-negative, that tells you that negative numbers are never mapped to by the square function.

The answer follows directly from that.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ .

### One one :

In order to check whether $f$ is one one or not, try to show that for **any** two points $x$ and $y$ , $$f(x) = f(y) \quad\iff\quad x=y$$ If so, then $f$ is one one. Otherwise not.

---

### Onto :

In order to check whether $f$ is onto or not, you'll have to check if for any $y\in\mathbb{R}$ , there exists **at least one** $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=y$ .

If so, then $f$ is onto. Otherwise, not.

---